# How do you right-click on Windows taskbar using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

I often need to right-click on Windows taskbar to see Pinned or Recent items on IDEs or Microsoft Office. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 1):

Through trial-and-error, I discovered that this is possible with `WinKey` + `Alt` + `Number` (`Alt` + `WinKey` + `Number`). Note that this works for numbers 0 through 9 and doesn't work for numeric keypad on the right.